# Is it possible to have one regex that solves this task?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
string = '1,23'
```

When a comma is present in the string, I want the regex to match the first digit (`\n`) after the comma e.g.`2`.

Sometimes the comma will not be there. When it's not present, I want the regex to match the first digit of the string e.g. `1`.

Also, we can't reverse the order of the string to solve this task.

I am genuinely stuck. The only idea I had was prepending this: `[,|nothing]`. I tried `''` to mean nothing but that didn't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This doesn't help me at all. Although new to regular expressions, I have wrote many and am genuinely stuck. In fact, some of my answers on SO have helped people make regexps. The link you associated this post with is for people asking 'what does this regexp mean'. My question is not doing this, it's asking if there's a regexp to solve this problem. I've seen many questions like mine and I think it's a fair question.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with OP. Wiktor is closing regex related questions with a blanket, generic and unhelpful question that does not address the issue at hand.

Comment: yes its possible, show us what you have tried so far

Comment: `[,|nothing)]` only matches a single char: `,`, `|`, `n`, `o`, `t`, `h`, `i`, `g` or `)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't literally mean 'nothing' I meant a value to represent nothing. This was an attempt to show you I had thought about the question. Your link is a great resource SO has - perhaps you can point me to the link that'd solve the question?

Comment: Ok, I see now, but I believe it is not something evident. You may try `s.match(/^(?:[^,]*,)?(\d)/)[1]`

Comment: @Nonik At the bottom of my question I say how an alternation operator might help - if I can have a value to represent 'nothing'. I'm fairly out of ideas though but if I did have an answer to this it'd be a good learning opportunity

Comment: You do not need to represent nothing. You may make a whole sequence of patterns optional.

Comment: Do you have options of not using regexp? I mean, [string.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) would be very helpful in your case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad.  I misread the regex.  You're right :)

Comment: Non regex way `string.includes(",")?string[string.indexOf(",")+1]:string[0]`

Comment: @Omkar The only problem is that you do not know if the char you fetch is a digit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True. When OP said *first digit of string* and *digit after comma*, I thought the string is only going to contain numbers separated by comma. I agree that it'll fail if the char is not a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match an optional sequence of chars other than a comma and then a comma at the start of a string, and then match and *capture* the digit with

```
/^(?:[^,]*,)?(\d)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q4x28w/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^,]*,)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[^,]*` - 0 any chars other than a comma
  - `,` - a comma
- `(\d)` - Capturing group 1: any digit

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const strs = ['123', '1,23'];
const rx = /^(?:[^,]*,)?(\d)/;
for (const s of strs) {
  const result = (s.match(rx) || ['',''])[1];
  // Or, const result = s.match(rx)?.[1] || "";
  console.log(s, '=>', result);
}
```